# When I wrote JavaScript in atom its color became white and now and all alther code is also becoming white

Tags: javascript, colors, atom-editor

The script is white.
[image]

After I hit enter after all code then it becomes color less, How would I solve this problem?

Comment: May be it is showing space and formatting issue. Run the code and check if page is coming up properly or not

Comment: The question is not well-formatted. Consider correcting the format and share screenshots of the issue you are facing for better results.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. Try copying parts of the code and paste it into a new html5 boilerplate